# Two complex analysis theorems and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a complex polynomial.

Lemma 1. There exists a number $c\in\mathbb{C}$, such that $|f(c)|\leq|f(z)|$, i.e. $c$ is the minimum of the function.

Lemma 2. For every $c\in\mathbb{C}$ with $f(c)\ne 0$, there exists a number $c'\in\mathbb{C}$, such that $|f(c')|<|f(c)|$.

In high school, we use this method to prove the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. According to lemma 1, there is a minimum, but lemma 2 contradicts this. Hence $f(c)=0$ and hence $c$ is a zero of $f(z)$.

1. How are the above two lemma's called in complex analysis?
2. Is this a correct way to prove the Fundamental Theorem (it's high school level, so it doesn't need to be too rigorous)?

Comment: I don't know a name for these. This would indeed be a correct proof, but it's not obvious to me how, precisely, you would prove Lemma 2.

Comment: Lemma 2 follows from the open mapping theorem, but I see no super-easy way to prove it without some theory for holomorphic functions.

Comment: @MikeMiller I found out it's called Argand's inequality: here is a proof helmut.knaust.info/class/201220_4303/FTAlgebra.pdf, but as a high school student with no preknowledge of complex analysis I have a lot of trouble understandig it

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed interesting that such an elementary 'high-school level' proof exists; the OP might be interested in looking at another "in the same vein" question from this site:

[Proof of fundamental theorem of algebra in Baby Rudin](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2354334/432081)

The best way to answer your questions is to present a high school level demonstration (including some motivational and explanatory text) of the FTA using elementary ideas such as Lemma 1 and Lemma 2.

---

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kz^{k}$ be a polynomial defined on $\mathbb {C}$ with 
all coefficients $a_k \in \mathbb {C}$ and  $a_n \ne 0$
(we also assume that $n \ge 1$).

Proposition 1: $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z) = \infty$.

As the complex number $z$ gets farther and farther away from $0$, the highest degree term $a_n z^n$ will begin to 'dominate the action', so that $f(z)$ also gets farther and farther away from $0$.

It isn't easy to crank out a graph of these functions (uh, you would need 4-dimensional graph paper!), but at least we don't have to worry about checking all those $+\infty$ and $+\infty$ cases as we did when studying real-valued functions.

It is worth pointing out that the extended complex numbers, $\mathbb {C}_{\infty} = \mathbb {C} \cup \infty$, can be looked at as a 2-dim sphere, and in higher mathematical discourse it is called the Riemann Sphere. The number $0$ is at the 'south pole' and $\infty$ is at the 'north pole'.

The student already knows how the function $g(z) = z^2$ maps circles $|z| = R$ on the complex plane. A fascinating thing to construct in the mind is to 'see' how this function is mapping $\mathbb {C}_{\infty}$ to itself. This function is a 2:1 surjective mapping, except at the 'poles', $g(0) = 0$ and $g(\infty) = \infty$.

Notice that Proposition 1 can be restated as follows:

Proposition 2: $\lim_{z\to\infty} |f(z)| = +\infty$, and the function
$z \mapsto |f(z)|$ 
goes from $\mathbb {C}$ to the interval $[0, +\infty)$, or, if you prefer,
$\mathbb {C}_{\infty} \to [0, +\infty]$.

The Extreme Value Theorem also works in this setting, allowing us to state that a minimum 'distance' from $0$ is in the image of $f$:

Proposition 3: There exists a number $c \in \mathbb {C}$ such that

$\tag 1  |f(c)| \le |f(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb {C}$.

If we can show that $|f(c)| = 0$, i.e. $f(c) = 0$ we would know that every polynomial of degree greater than $1$ has at least one complex number root. But then you could divide out by $z - c$, and continue this work to get all the roots (of course some roots may come with a multiplicity).

With some fancy footwork you might find a technique showing that $c$ is a root, but it is easier to just go for the contradiction.

Proposition 4: Let $g(z)$ be any non-constant polynomial such that $g(z_0) \ne 0$. Then a complex number $z_1$, close to $z_0$,  can be found such that

$\tag 2 |g(z_1)| \lt |g(z_0)|$

Proof

Using the linear variable substitution, $h(z) = g(z + z_0)$, we would have $h(0) = g(z_0)$. So, without loss of generality, we can just assume that $z_0 = 0$. Now when we went to $\infty$ the highest power 'dominates' the action, but as we approach $0$, the term right after the constant is the most important since it goes to $0$ more slowly. By approaching $0$ in the right manner, aligning with the negative of $g(0)$ , we can erase part of the constant 0-th power term. Instead of carefully completing this proof, we leave it to the student; they will have to use the triangle inequality and understand the following key idea:

Lemma: Let $h(z) = a + b z^m$,  so that $h(0) = a$. There exist numbers $z_1$ as close to $0$ as necessary satifying
$|h(z_1)| \lt |h(0)| = a$.
Proof
For $0 \lt \lambda \lt 1$, we want to find a $z_1$ with
$h(z_1) = a + b {z_1}^m = \lambda a$. But we can solve for $z_1$,

$\quad z_1 = \sqrt [m] \frac{(\lambda - 1) a}{b}$

Note that $|z_1| = \sqrt [m] {\lambda - 1} \;  \sqrt [m] \frac{| a|}{|b|}$, and so $\lambda$ controls the modulus of $z_1$.

Theorem 5: Any non-constant polynomial $f$ over the complex numbers has $n$ roots.

Proof

By Proposition 3 we can find a complex number such that the image under the function $f$ is at a minimum distance from $0$. Assume this distance in not equal to zero. But then by Proposition 4 we can find values in the range of $f$ that are even closer to $0$; this is a contradiction.

Comment: I've seen this proof before but what I'm wondering about now is a high-school level proof that $|f|$ attains a minimum:  Since $|f(z)|\to \infty$ uniformly as $|z|\to \infty,$ there exists $r>0$ such that $|z|>r\implies |f(z)|>|f(0)|$  so it suffices to show that $\min \{|f(z)|: r\geq |z|\}$ exists.... From an advanced view, $|f|$ is continuous and $\{z: r\geq |z|\}$ is compact.... Is there a $brief$ 
 high-school level  method,  only for polynomial $f$?...................+1

Comment: Gaus' first proof ot the Fund. Th'm of Algebra was to show that the graphs of $g(x,y) =0$ and $h(x,y)=0,$ in $\mathbb R^2,$ will intersect, where  $x=Re(z), y=Im(z)$ and $g=Re(f(z)) , h=Im(f(z)).$  E.g. when $ f(z)=z^2+1$ then g  is a hyperbola whose asymptotes are the lines $ y=\pm x$, and $g$ is a hyperbola whose asymptotes are the co-ordinate axes.

Comment: @dan IVT EVT for polynomials!  See
Simon Stevin IVT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_Stevin#Mathematics
Rolle's Theorem (give him credit anyway): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem#History

HS Brief Method? Hand waving works best!